# Why does Music.SE say I retracted a close vote when I did not?

Tags: support

I voted to close this question: [In terms of sound, what are the advantages of a steel or nylon string?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/126312/in-terms-of-sound-what-are-the-advantages-of-a-steel-or-nylon-string)

It is now open, but it doesn't seem to have been reopened(?)

I did not retract my close vote for this question, but when I try to vote to close it again (because to me it has hardly been changed at all and still is either unclear or a duplicate), I get the message:

> You cannot vote to close again after retracting your vote

I did not retract my vote. Is the message worded inaccurately or is something wrong?

Comment: Based on this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes/5213#5213. It seems like bad messaging. It does not seem like you can cast close votes twice regardless on how they are invalidated.

Comment: I've had a similar experience, which I took to be consistent with @Dom's explanation. The restriction on close voting itself makes sense, but it seems like it should be allowed if the question has been edited before or after reopening.

Comment: This bug is reported on Meta SE here: [When a retraction is not a retraction. Please update close-menu message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376335)